# how to communicate android application to mysql database through JSP and Servlet

Tags: java, android, mysql

I am creating an android application and I want that when user fill up the registration form in my android application then that data should be saved in remote MySQL database.But i want JSP and Servlet for this as middle level.
I searched a lot on internet but every tutorial shown on internet are using PHP. I don't want to use PHP at server side.
So is there any tutorial or resource for saving android application data to remote MySQL database using JSP and Servlet.

Comment: JSP is a technology to create web pages (TML) on the server side, to view the pages your app would have to display a web client such as WebView. Are you sure you want a HTML page for the registration form, instead of native Android controls?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Look at the way servlet is deployed from the below blog :

http://hmkcode.com/java-servlet-send-receive-json-using-jquery-ajax/

Hit the servlet URL in a browser.If u get the JSON response, the same call can be leveraged from the mobile client building the URLconnection and rendered in the app using some Parser at Mobile end.
Hope this meets the requirement.

Answer (score 1):

You usually call RESTful services from the Android App. The RESTful services can be written in any language of your choice. Your Android client is one which is communicating with the REST Backend. If you are using ButtonView and on the click of it some update or retrieval are supposed to be performed then REST based services are best.
I would recommend this approach.